# How to mock Google API AndroidPublisher request

Tags: java, android, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

I've got a class that makes a request to the AndroidPublisher API to get the [Purchases.Subscriptions.get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) resource. How does one mock out the OAuth request and call to get the subscription resource using the classes from the package com.google.api.client.testing?

Here is the code to get the subscription:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder().build();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId("email")
    .setServiceAccountScopes(singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER))
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("file.p12"))
    .build();
AndroidPublisher androidPublisher = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
    .setApplicationName("appname")
    .build();
AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get get = androidPublisher.purchases().subscriptions().get(
    "appname",
    "productId",
    "purchaseToken");
SubscriptionPurchase subscription = get.execute();
System.out.println(subscription.toPrettyString());
```

Here is how I am currently, but unsuccessfully, trying to mock out the JSON responses:

```
MockLowLevelHttpResponse mockResponse = new MockLowLevelHttpResponse();
mockResponse.setStatusCode(200);
mockResponse.setContentType(Json.MEDIA_TYPE);
mockResponse.setContent("{\n" +
        "  \"autoRenewing\" : true,\n" +
        "  \"countryCode\" : \"US\",\n" +
        "  \"developerPayload\" : \"\",\n" +
        "  \"expiryTimeMillis\" : \"1480019001357\",\n" +
        "  \"kind\" : \"androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase\",\n" +
        "  \"paymentState\" : 1,\n" +
        "  \"priceAmountMicros\" : \"990000\",\n" +
        "  \"priceCurrencyCode\" : \"USD\",\n" +
        "  \"startTimeMillis\" : \"1477333413210\"\n" +
        "}");
return new MockHttpTransport.Builder().setLowLevelHttpResponse(mockResponse).build();
```

When I run the test with the mock classes I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no JSON input found
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:49)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.startParsing(JsonParser.java:223)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:380)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:355)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

What am I missing? How does one mock out the OAuth2 response as well as the call to get the subscription?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185190/how-to-access-google-developer-api-in-android-app pls ans this

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure out my issue. In addition to mocking out the HttpTransport I also had to provide a mock GoogleCredential like:

```
new MockGoogleCredential.Builder().build();
```

Comment: hey @james. 
I am stuck at same problem. Do u mind sharing a gist/code for this. That would be really helpful.

Comment: @james https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185190/how-to-access-google-developer-api-in-android-app  pls ans this

Answer (score 0):

@Sukhmeet Singh I'm not sure what your deployment environment is like but we are using Spring Boot. I have the following spring beans declared in a `@Configuration` file.

```
@Bean
public HttpTransport httpTransport() {
    return new NetHttpTransport.Builder().build();
}

@Bean
public JsonFactory jsonFactory() {
    return JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
}

@Bean
public GoogleCredential googleCredential(
        final HttpTransport httpTransport,
        final JsonFactory jsonFactory) {
    final String serviceAccountUserName = env.getRequiredProperty("<redacted>");
    final String serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile = env.getRequiredProperty("<redacted>");
    try {
        return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountUserName)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile))
                .build();
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

@Bean
public AndroidPublisher androidPublisher(
        final GoogleAppPackageName googleAppPackageName,
        final HttpTransport httpTransport,
        final JsonFactory jsonFactory,
        final GoogleCredential googleCredential) {
    return new AndroidPublisher.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, googleCredential)
            .setApplicationName(googleAppPackageName.getValue())
            .build();
}
```

Then in my integration tests, specifically we are using cucumber-jvm, I have another test specific `@Configuration` file that overrides those beans using the spring annotation `@Primary`.

```
@Primary
@Bean
public GoogleCredential googleCredential() {
    return new MockGoogleCredential.Builder().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean
public HttpTransport httpTransport() {
    final MockLowLevelHttpResponse mockResponse = new MockLowLevelHttpResponse();
    mockResponse.setStatusCode(200);
    mockResponse.setContentType(Json.MEDIA_TYPE);
    mockResponse.setContent("<desired JSON response>");

    final MockLowLevelHttpRequest request = new MockLowLevelHttpRequest(url);
    request.setResponse(mockResponse);
    return request;
}
```

Now I have some other classes that I use to help me mock out multiple responses for different scenario's but this should give you enough of an idea to figure it out.

Hope it helps.